# What is sfdocready?

Tags: html, xml

I see sfdocready in some footers of pages I have been working on. I cannot find anything about this?

For example:

```
<sfdocready id="sfDocReady"></sfdocready>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Cant find very much about it. You use Firefox?

Comment: I would assume there is (or could be) a js function attached to its `onload` event that would fire off some code for whatever "sf" is so that it knows enough of the document is loaded to safely run that function. As to what "sf" is, I have no idea.

Comment: None of my JS are running anything that has to do with it. that is the strange part...

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with [Superfish](http://wwws.superfish.com/) (the `<sfdocready>` and `<sfmsg>` tags).

I just determined what was doing it in my case. Using Safari, I have (well, had, it's gone now for this bizarre behavior) the Awesome Screenshot extension installed. There is a checkbox in its settings called "Enable similar product search powered by Superfish" which looks for images on the page and uses them as search parameters to provide comparison shopping deals for you.

In its defense it did prompt me if I wanted to see price comparisons, but it did so on Amazon in a way that actually looked like the prompt came from Amazon.

To the answer above me about Firefox inserting it when you save the document, that's only because an extension or some JavaScript inserted it first, it has nothing specific to do with Firefox. It also has nothing to do with Wordpress.

Somewhat sleazy stuff, imo.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it's got something to do with Wordpress themes.

Comment: Definitely - it appears in some, but not all, Wordpress themes and pages. Yet it's also appeared in at least one Drupal web page issue (http://drupal.org/node/1144530). Vexing...

Comment: Seems like no one knows what this is??? http://themeforest.net/forums/thread/sfdocready-/41054

Comment: <sfmsg> looks like a hack but its something to do with WP

Answer (score 0):

I have, an assumption, that this tag means: "safe document is ready", so something is running only after whole document has been loaded. But what exectly does it mean and how does it work, it`s a big question.

Near this tag I have also also often seen `<sfmsg>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

This tag is inserted by Firefox when you save the page as an HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

I issued this problem yesterday. I have firefox with a plugin named `Awesome Screenshot`. In order to solve this you need:

1. Click over the Awesome Screenshot
2. Select `options`
3. UNCHECK/DISABLE the option: "Enable similar product search powered by Superfish"

And that is all!